# 「捨ててしまう」Why are there two て’s used here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjugations, て-form

The full sentence was :

> 「捨ててしまうのはもったいないと思って」
>   I think to throw away (something) is a waste

But why are there two て’s?
Why is it not 捨てしまう？

Comment: That sentence reads to me more like "I thought it was a waste to throw it away".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The verb is 捨てる, so its て-form is 捨てて, hence the compound form Vて+しまう becomes 捨ててしまう.

If it were the casual ちゃう instead of しまう that you were using, that starts from the て-form too, but also contracts the て, so it would instead be 捨てちゃう, with just the one て. Perhaps that is where the confusion arose?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

/group 1-1 /  (-aる,-uる,-oる→って)

止まる(tomaru)+しまう=止まってしまう

売る(uru)+しまう=売ってしまう

取る(toru)+しまう=取ってしまう

/group 1-2/   (-iる,-eる→て or って)

着る(kiru)+しまう=着てしまう

経る(heru)+しまう=経てしまう

止める(tomeru)+しまう=止めてしまう

切る(kiru)+しまう=切ってしまう

減る(heru)+しまう=減ってしまう

/group 2/   -す→して

殺す(korosu)+しまう=殺してしまう

刺す(sasu)+しまう=刺してしまう

/group 3/   -く,-ぐ→いて

書く(kaku)+しまう=書いてしまう

研ぐ(togu)+しまう=研いでしまう

/group 4/   -う,-つ→って

買う(kau)+しまう=買ってしまう

勝つ(katsu)+しまう=勝ってしまう

/group 5/   -む,-ぶ→んで

畳む(tatamu)+しまう=畳んでしまう

飛ぶ(tobu)+しまう=飛んでしまう